# use erlang WebAppmon to show process tree get error lists,append,2 badarg

Tags: erlang

```
{badarg,
               [{erlang,'++',
                    [error,
                     [{mgeew_letter_server,"4358.603.0",supervisor,
                          [mgeew_letter_server]},
                      {mgeew_skill_server,"4358.602.0",worker,[mgeew_skill_server]},
                      {mod_team_server,"4358.601.0",worker,[mod_team_server]},
                      {mod_team_sup,"4358.600.0",supervisor,[mod_team_sup]},
                      {mod_family_manager,"4358.596.0",worker,[mod_family_manager]},
                      {mod_family_sup,"4358.595.0",supervisor,[mod_family_sup]},
                      {mod_family_data_server,"4358.594.0",worker,
                          [mod_family_data_server]},
                      {mgeew_country_treasure_log_server,"4358.593.0",worker,
                          [mgeew_country_treasure_log_server]},
                      {mgeew_bank_sheet_log_server,"4358.592.0",worker,
                          [mgeew_bank_sheet_log_server]},
                      {mgeew_loop_mission_log_server,"4358.591.0",worker,
                          [mgeew_loop_mission_log_server]},
                      {mgeew_mission_log_server,"4358.590.0",worker,
                          [mgeew_mission_log_server]},
                      {mgeew_super_item_log_server,"4358.589.0",worker,
                          [mgeew_super_item_log_server]},
                      {mgeew_pet_log_server,"4358.588.0",worker,
                          [mgeew_pet_log_server]},
                      {common_item_log_server,"4358.587.0",worker,
                          [common_item_log_server]},
                      {common_general_log_server,"4358.586.0",worker,
                          [common_general_log_server]},
                      {mgeew_consume_log_server,"4358.585.0",worker,
                          [mgeew_consume_log_server]},
                      {mgeew_behavior_log_server,"4358.584.0",worker,
                          [mgeew_behavior_log_server]},
                      {mgeew_system_buff,"4358.583.0",worker,[mgeew_system_buff]},
                      {mgeew_event,"4358.582.0",worker,[mgeew_event]},
                      {mgeew_office,"4358.581.0",worker,[mgeew_office]},
                      {mgeew_pay_server,"4358.577.0",worker,[mgeew_pay_server]},
                      {mgeew_user_event,"4358.576.0",worker,[mgeew_user_event]},
                      {db_role_rank_info_subscriber,"4358.574.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_friend_subscriber,"4358.572.0",worker,[db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_exe_fb_info_subscriber,"4358.570.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_sq_fb_info_subscriber,"4358.568.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_family_donate_subscriber,"4358.566.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_activity_reward_subscriber,"4358.564.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_world_counter_subscriber,"4358.562.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_offline_msg_subscriber,"4358.560.0",worker,[db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_money_event_counter_subscriber,"4358.558.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_money_event_subscriber,"4358.556.0",worker,[db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_rece_flowers_this_week_rank_subscriber,"4358.554.0",
                          worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_give_flowers_this_week_rank_subscriber,"4358.552.0",
                          worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_rece_flowers_last_week_rank_subscriber,"4358.550.0",
                          worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_give_flowers_last_week_rank_subscriber,"4358.548.0",
                          worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_rece_flowers_yesterday_rank_subscriber,"4358.546.0",
                          worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_rece_flowers_today_rank_subscriber,"4358.544.0",
                          worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_rece_flowers_rank_subscriber,"4358.542.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_give_flowers_yesterday_rank_subscriber,"4358.540.0",
                          worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_give_flowers_today_rank_subscriber,"4358.538.0",
                          worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_give_flowers_rank_subscriber,"4358.536.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_event_state_subscriber,"4358.534.0",worker,[db_subscriber]},
                      {db_waroffaction_counter_subscriber,"4358.532.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_waroffaction_record_subscriber,"4358.530.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_faction_subscriber,"4358.528.0",worker,[db_subscriber]},
                      {db_pay_log_index_subscriber,"4358.526.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_pay_log_subscriber,"4358.524.0",worker,[db_subscriber]},
                      {db_pet_understanding_rank_subscriber,"4358.522.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_pet_rank_subscriber,"4358.520.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_family_gongxun_persistent_rank_subscriber,"4358.518.0",
                          worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_yesterday_gongxun_rank_subscriber,"4358.516.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_today_gongxun_rank_subscriber,"4358.514.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_gongxun_rank_subscriber,"4358.512.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_equip_stone_rank_subscriber,"4358.510.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_equip_reinforce_rank_subscriber,"4358.508.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_magic_equip_rank_subscriber,"4358.506.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_equip_refining_rank_subscriber,"4358.504.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_family_active_rank_subscriber,"4358.502.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_world_pkpoint_rank_subscriber,"4358.500.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_pkpoint_rank_subscriber,"4358.498.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_level_rank_subscriber,"4358.496.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_system_config_subscriber,"4358.494.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_shortcut_bar_subscriber,"4358.492.0",worker,[db_subscriber]},
                      {db_bank_sheets_subscriber,"4358.490.0",worker,[db_subscriber]},
                      {db_common_letter_subscriber,"4358.488.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_family_assets_subscriber,"4358.486.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_family_skill_research_subscriber,"4358.484.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_warofking_subscriber,"4358.482.0",worker,[db_subscriber]},
                      {db_title_counter_subscriber,"4358.480.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_spec_title_subscriber,"4358.478.0",worker,[db_subscriber]},
                      {db_normal_title_subscriber,"4358.476.0",worker,[db_subscriber]},
                      {db_warofking_history_index_subscriber,"4358.474.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_family_request_subscriber,"4358.472.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_family_invite_subscriber,"4358.470.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_family_parttake_subscriber,"4358.468.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_family_ext_subscriber,"4358.466.0",worker,[db_subscriber]},
                      {db_family_subscriber,"4358.464.0",worker,[db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_ext_subscriber,"4358.462.0",worker,[db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_attr_subscriber,"4358.460.0",worker,[db_subscriber]},
                      {db_role_base_subscriber,"4358.458.0",worker,[db_subscriber]},
                      {db_family_counter_subscriber,"4358.456.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_broadcast_message_subscriber,"4358.454.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {db_bank_buy_subscriber,"4358.452.0",worker,[db_subscriber]},
                      {db_bank_sell_subscriber,"4358.450.0",worker,[db_subscriber]},
                      {db_sheet_counter_subscriber,"4358.448.0",worker,
                          [db_subscriber]},
                      {mgeew_config,"4358.58.0",worker,[mgeew_config]},
                      {common_role_line_map,"4358.57.0",worker,
                          [common_role_line_map]}
                     ]
                    ]
                },
                {lists,append,2},
                {process_info,get_by_supervisors,3},
                {process_info,mark_supervisors_workers,3},
                {process_info,fix_links,3},
                {process_info,build_graph,5},
                {process_info,start_collecting_data,3},
                {process_info,handle_call,3}
               ]
        }
```

When I start the erlang nodes and start the webtool by webtool:start(standard_path,[{port,8888},{bind_address,{0,0,0,0}},{server_name, "kfweb"}]).
And start the WebAppmon and click the process to show the process tree of it.
And it can not show and get the error in the shell.
Can anyone tell me what happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
vi /dist/src/otp_src_R14A/lib/appmon/src/process_info.erl
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Find:
Children = supervisor:which_children(Pid),
Chg With:
    case supervisor:which_children(Pid) of
    [_] = Children ->
        next;
    _ ->
        Children = []
    end,
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
cd /dist/src/otp_src_R14A
make
make install
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
mt_common:load_nodes(process_info).
```